# Rotate a object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rotation, glrotate

I want to move an objecto in OpenGL. I draw the object in (0,0,0), if the object is on that point it rotates fine (using the center of the object as reference to rotate). The problem comes when I move the object, it rotates using the same point as reference and not the point where it is. The code is:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(xangle,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(yangle,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(zangle,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glTranslatef(x,y,z);
//draw object
    glPopMatrix();
```

Does anyone know what it have to do so the object always rotates using the point where it is as reference?

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/16721/1134 =)

Comment: Thanks :). To translate the point what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reorder your transformations:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x,y,z);
glRotatef(xangle,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glRotatef(yangle,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
glRotatef(zangle,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
//draw object
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: If I do that the object rotates fine, but then the problem is translating (it has a front and back part) because it can translates moving the sides when it should move using the front or back.

Comment: I don't understand. What front and back part? What side is moving when it shouldn't?

Comment: The object has a front and a back part and i move it forward and backward with the keyboard using the translate. If the translate is before the rotates and I rotate the object then the object doesn't move on the direction of the front/back part.

Comment: Then you should not store the rotation and translation separated from each other, but as one matrix. You then can apply rotations and translations as you need. The reason why you see this behaviour is that the translation vector must be rotated, too.